# Reactjs select value opition value map iteration with default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop

I am using react application in iteration I have a map method  with some doubt, I have a select box with fill number based on iteration 0 to coming value base,my expected output is [{label:0,value:0},{label:1,value:1},{label:2,value:2}] but coming output is =[{label:1,value:1},{label:2,value:2}], I know how to do in for loop but, i want know map method beacuse i am react application,i tried fill , and join method it's not working please help uss

```
let value = 2
[...Array(parseInt(value)).keys()].map((x, index) => (
    {
      label: x + 1,
      value: x + 1,
   }
 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array(2);` will create an empty array with length is 2, so when you want your array is [0, 1, 2], the length should be `Array(3);`. So I update your code into `Array(value + 1)` and remove `parseInt`.

```js
let value = 2
const result = [...Array(value + 1).keys()].map((x) => ({
  label: x,
  value: x,
}))

console.log(result);
```